# Highlighting subroutines in Notepad++

Tags: windows, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I would like to highlight the contents of `IF` statements in a slightly different colour from the background, so that I can see them more easily.

Is it possible in Notepad++?

it would be amazing to highlight all the nested subroutines in a function in slightly different light/dark colours depending on the scheme so that you can straightaway see the commands at a glance without spying out the curly brackets. not psychedelic colours, just slightly visible background colour difference. wouldn't it be great?

```
Function Foo(){
   highlight one color
     if(){highlight color2
       for(){highlight color3
          if (){hilghlight color4
          }
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would also like to know this answer. Have you found a solution and/or a different editor that supports this feature?

Answer (score -1):

Notepad++ supports syntax highlighting, it looks like your code is VB?  Select the following from the drop down menu;

[image: Language syntax selection]

Comment: By the way, C# doesn't have a `Function` keyword. That looks like VB.